# Krakend propogate nested claims

Tags: krakend

```
"alg": "RS256",
"roles_key": "realm_access.roles",
"roles_key_is_nested": true,
"propagate_claims": [["realm_access.roles", "x-roles"]]
```

I have the above config but Krakend v2 is not able to propagate claims in X-Roles key.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add in the `input_headers`  the `x-roles` as well, otherwise KrakenD will block it from passing to the backend.

Comment: Hi @alo

If it still not works then ?